# Can't map Ctrl + minus in Emacs in Mac OS X

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I'm trying to map Ctrl + minus ("C--") to undo in Emacs 24.3 (from http://emacsformacosx.com) in Mac OS X 10.8.4, but I can't get it to work. There seems to be some very global key binding for decreasing the font size, which I can't seem to override. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I have the following in my .emacs.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C--") 'undo)    ;; Doesn't work
(global-set-key (kbd "C-u") 'undo)    ;; Just for testing, does work
```

When I press Ctrl+U, it triggers undo, but when I press Ctrl+minus, it decreases the font size. It might be simply that I should use something other than "C--", but it looks like it should work. I checked the key bindings (via C-h b) and there, C-u is bound to undo, but C-- is bound to text-scale-decrease. It would probably be possible to find where that key is bound and get some clue, but my Emacs-fu is too weak.

I'm using the graphical version of Emacs, not the terminal version.

Comment: Have you tried entering a different mode to see if the key bindings that are trumping you are mode specific or global?  That will affect how you deal with the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With these type of problems I usually
try <kbd>f1 k</kbd> and right after the key combination that I'm having a problem with,
<kbd>C--</kbd> in your case.
One of two things should happen:

1. Nothing happens - this means that the shortcut is being intercepted
   at the level of the operating system.
2. It gives you a description of a function that's being called.
   It's probable that it was set by either your major mode or one of the minor modes.
   So you should investigate that as well, searching though the references
   to this function, which is `text-scale-decrease` in you case.
   After you find either `global-set-key`, or `local-set-key` or `define-key`
   with this function, either comment it out, or better just
   call the same function with same shortcut and  `nil` in your `~/.emacs`.

### UPD: how to unset a key

When you find that some source that you're loading e.g. `starter-kit` is setting the key,
you just need to unset it later in the same way:

1. If it was set with `(global-set-key (kbd "C--") 'text-scale-decrease)`,
   you unset it with `(global-set-key (kbd "C--") nil)`.
2. If it was set with `(define-key markdown-mode-map (kbd "C--") 'text-scale-descrease)`,
   you unset it with `(define-key markdown-mode-map (kbd "C--") nil)`.
3. If it was set with

   (add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook
       (lambda()(local-set-key (kbd "C--") 'text-scale-descrease))

   you unset with

   (add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook
       (lambda()(local-set-key (kbd "C--") nil))

Comment: Thanks. I had actually done that too, and the key works. But you nudged me in the right direction, and it turns out that I had installed the "starter-kit" packages, and the offending binding was in starter-kit-bindings. So removing it solved my problem. But I'm still curious how I would leave it installed and still override the binding.