# Delete key not working using emacs in Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal, emacs24, emacs23

I'm new in emacs. I want to code with it but it arose my first problem is that my delete key is not working (imagine coding without using this key). When I type appear the following message: "C-h (Type ? for further options)-". What can I do to set the delete key?

I'm working in a mac Terminal.
I'll appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Add the line:
(keyboard-translate ?\C-h ?\C-?)
to your .emacs file in your home folder.

Answer (score 1):

I'd answer the same as for:

[Can't map Ctrl + minus in Emacs in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784902/cant-map-ctrl-minus-in-emacs-in-mac-os-x/)

And just to add, when you're new with emacs, and something doesn't work and you think it should, try launching it with `emacs -q`. This way it doesn't load any custom code.